# Optional enumeration environment

Tags: enumerate, enumitem

Please just help me to create a enumerated environment like the one shown below with number 1,2. Thank you very much[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Po9CB.jpg)

I tried with:

```
\begin {enumerate} [option]
\item
\end {enumerate}
```

but not possible

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It would be great if you could  show us what you have tried. Posting a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that indicates what you are trying to do makes it easier for people to understand what you want. It also makes it easier for people to help you, since they have some code to start from, and hence much more likely that some one will try to help you.

Comment: thank you. i tried with
\ begin {enumerate} [option]
\ item
\ end {enumerate}

Comment: You really should post a complete [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228): this is a minimal piece of code that compiles and demonstrates your problem...but see below.

Comment: What option(s)?  Did you load any packages?

Comment: I have no idea for the option of to get such results!

Comment: Please post a minimal working example. Is this in Beamer? Are you loading `enumitem` or `enumerate`? What does 'not possible' mean? Did you get an error?

Comment: You can highlight code in your post using back-ticks. To highlight code-blocks, either indent them by four spaces or use the `{}` on the gui.

Comment: “I have no idea for the option of to get such results!”: this means that you haven’t actually tried anything, have you? ;-)

Comment: @GuM thank you i have tried to finish it but i'm new to latex and can not do it

Comment: @NgôVănToàn: Never mind, I was just teasing you… (:-)  People on the TeX.SX site is somewhat reluctant to answer “Do this for me”-type questions; sometimes this kind of questions are asked by students who are given an assignment for a LaTeX course and are trying to cheat.  Of course, I’m not implying that this is your case.

Comment: @GuM:  I was also hesitant to go out and try to finish it but my latex capital was not good. I did not know about the TeX.SX web and did not really know that, thank you for telling me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [pifont](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pifont) package provides circled numbers as `\ding{182}`, `\ding{183}`, .... Here is a hack using the [enumitem](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package to use these numbers in an enumerate environment to produce:

[image]

...and here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{pifont}
\begin{document}

  \begin{enumerate}[label=\ding{\numexpr181+\arabic*\relax}]
    \item one
    \item two
  \end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

If you are going to be using this often you probably want to define you own `enumerate` style:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{pifont}
\newlist{numbered}{enumerate}{4}
\setlist[numbered]{label=\ding{\numexpr181+\arabic*\relax}}
\begin{document}

  \begin{numbered}
    \item one
    \item two
  \end{numbered}

\end{document}
```

**EDIT**

Here is a coloured variant:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\newlist{numbered}{enumerate}{4}
\setlist[numbered]{
  label=\textcolor{NavyBlue}{\ding{\numexpr181+\arabic*\relax}}
}
\begin{document}

  \begin{numbered}
    \item one
    \item two
  \end{numbered}

\end{document}
```

See the [xcolor](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xcolor) manual for the list of colours that it supports.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much my problem is so and you helped me finish it!

Comment: @NgôVănToàn: Note that you can *both* accept the answer *and* upvote it—if you deem it appropriate, of course…

Comment: I tried to change the color of the numbers 1,2 but not, so how to change the color for the number 1,2?

Comment: @NgôVănToàn See my edit

Comment: How to change \arabic to \alpha? With overleaf.com, I get a compilation error (Missing number, treated as zero).

Comment: @pzorba75 This question asks specifically about circled *numbers*. This approach is not going to work with circled *letters* because the [pifont](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pifont) package does not provide them. You'll have to ask a new question -- or try searching TeX.SX as this has probably been asked before.